# Can we use a Bluetooth thermal printer using flutter_blue package

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter mobile app , I need to  implement a Bluetooth thermal printer, So I have added flutter_blue package, and using esc_pos_utils 1.0.0  for generating byte code but I am not getting way how can I use byte code with flutter_blue package, I have used esc_pos_bluetooth, but problem is, it not detecting device in some mobile, If flutter_bluetooth_serial: ^0.2.2 can use for that will also use cause flutter_blue  and  flutter_bluetooth_serial are working  well for detecting device in almost every mobile.

Also I have used bluetooth_print , it working better then esc_pos_bluetooth in detecting mobile device but it is using LineText widget which not good  for  generating receipt,
Please help me out

Comment: Maybe this article helps: https://hackernoon.com/build-an-app-that-print-from-a-thermal-bluetooth-printer-using-flutter